# Bootstrap 3 form columns not collapsing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get some columns to collapse:

```
 <div class="container sign-up-form-container">
     <form>
         <div class="row">
             <input type="text" name="suFullName" placeholder="Full Name" class="input-text col-xs-12" autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <input type="text" name="suEmail" placeholder="Email" class="input-text col-xs-6" id="sign-up-email">
               <input type="password" name="suPassword" placeholder="Password" class="input-text col-xs-6" id="sign-up-password">
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <input type="checkbox" name="suAgree" id="sign-up-agree"><label class="text-minor" for="sign-up-agree" id="sign-up-agree-description">I agree to the <a>Terms of Service</a> and <a>Privacy Policy</a>.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="submit" class="cta-sign-up" value="Sign Up For Free">
             </div>
         </form>
     </div>
```

However the

```
 <input type="text" name="suEmail" placeholder="Email" class="input-text col-xs-6" id="sign-up-email">
 <input type="password" name="suPassword" placeholder="Password" class="input-text col-xs-6" id="sign-up-password">
```

are not collapsing on resize. How do I make them collapse?

Answer (score 0):

At first BOOTSRAP require , that every row must be in class="container" or class="container-fluid" . In your example I see , that YOU take one container for all rows. Your checkboxes don't have grid classes like col-xs-**  col-sm-**(you can use empty classes to position your checkboxes  , for example you take three col-sm-4 . In the first column you put element . The next two you leave empty. In this case you can position your element , where you want) . Add  class="form-control" in every input .